# Como sortear os objetos de um array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Possuo na variável `optionsPergunta` um array de objeto e preciso sortear a posição dos objetos deste array:

```
 "options": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "book_unit_question_id": 2,
                "description": "get",
                "image_sound": null,
                "correct": true,
                "status": false,
                "user_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:27",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:27"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "book_unit_question_id": 2,
                "description": "are",
                "image_sound": null,
                "correct": false,
                "status": false,
                "user_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:21",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:33"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "book_unit_question_id": 2,
                "description": "go to",
                "image_sound": null,
                "correct": false,
                "status": false,
                "user_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:39",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:39"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "book_unit_question_id": 2,
                "description": "move",
                "image_sound": null,
                "correct": false,
                "status": false,
                "user_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:43",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-27 16:06:43"
            }
        ]
```

Tentei algo como:

```
optionsPergunta.sort(this.sorteiaArray)

sorteiaArray(){
   return Math.random() < Math.random()
}
```

Porém ao mostrar o conteudo de optionsPergunta, eu permaneço com os objetos na mesma posição.

Comment: Talvez para mim não ficou claro, são todas as posições ou você quer pegar um posição em aleatório?

Comment: Acredito que por "sortear" você queira dizer "ordenar". Se for o caso, por qual campo você gostaria de ordenar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue com `Array destructuring`.

Segue exemplo:

```js
//gerar um Array com 30 itens para teste
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  arr.push({id: i, item: `Item: ${i}`});
}       

//Código para ordenar o Array de forma aletória
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
 [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
}
         
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Se tratando de números aleatórios você pode utilizar a o metodo Math.random() esse método traz uma numeração entre zero(0) e um(1) ex: 1.x números ou 0.x números, para não se trazer apenas essa variante e percorrermos todo o array podemos utilizar uma função, e em seu retorno podemos arredondar para baixo, para isso utilizamos Math.floor()

```
radom = (max, min) => { 
    let valor = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    return Math.floor(valor)
}
console.log(radom(options.length,0))
```

em relação a função sort, ela faz um ordenação do array: [array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

A ideia aqui é enquanto o array `options` tiver elementos, será sorteado um numero (do zero até ao ultimo indice) que será o elemento do `index` para retirar ao array `options`. Depois adicionado ao `optionsPergunta`

```js
const options = [
    { "id": 6 },
    { "id": 5 },
    { "id": 7 },
    { "id": 8 }
];

const optionsPergunta = [];

while (options.length) {

    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length - 1);

    const [option] = options.splice(index, 1);

    optionsPergunta.push(option);
}

console.log(optionsPergunta);
```